# Pizza Toppings Ordering Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

So here's the question:

The menu at a pizza place offers 14 possible toppings from 3 categories. Customers circle the toppings that they want on the order pad. (The order of circles or order of toppings does not matter.)

Veggie (7): Mushrooms, Peppers, Onions, Olives, Capers, Artichoke, Pineapple
Meat (5): Salami, Pepperoni, Ham, Salmon, Anchovies
Cheese (2): Mozzarella, Feta

1. In how many ways can a customer's order pad choose exactly one topping from each category?
2. In how many ways can an order choose exactly two toppings from each category, if they aren't allowed to circle a topping twice (i.e no repeats)?
3. In how many ways can an order pad choose up to two toppings from each category, if they aren't allowed to circle a topping twice? (No toppings are allowed).
4. In how many ways can an order pad choose exactly two toppings from each category, i they are allowed to circle a topping twice (i.e, repeats allowed)?
5. In how many different possible orders are there for Veggie-topping-only pizzas with at least two toppings, if repeated toppings are not allowed?

And here are my answers:

1. $C(7, 1) + C(5, 1) + C(2, 1)$
2. $C(7, 1) + C(6, 1) + C(5, 1) + C(4, 1) + C(2, 1) + C(1, 1)$
3. $C(7, 2) + C(5, 2) + (2, 2)$
4. $\frac{(7 + 2 - 1)!}{2!(7 -1)!}\cdot\frac{  (5 + 2 - 1)!}{2!(5 -1)! }\cdot \frac{(2 + 2 - 1)!}{2!(2-1)!} $
5. $C(7, 2)$

Did I work the problems out correctly? If not, what's wrong with my answers?

```
My justifications:
```

1. For number 1, the question is asking for one topping from each category. The order doesn't matter so it's a combination problem. The first and second digit represent the total number of choices and the number of options you are allowed to pick, respectively. Thanks to the kind users in the comment section, I know understand that I was wrong to put in addition symbols, and that there should in fact be multiplication symbols in number 1.
2. This problem is very similar to number one except you can't repeat toppings. This means that the number of options you have to chose from the second time around are one less.
3. This one was rather tricky, and I doubt my answer here but I simply applied combination logic (i.e total number of choices, how many you are allowed to choose).
4. Here repetition is allowed so I picked the proper combination formula for that: $\frac{(n + r - 1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$
5. This problem asked only for the veggie topping pizzas with at least two toppings, so the answer was $C(7, 2).$

Comment: Think about if you only had $1$ choice in each category. By your logic the answer to question 1. would be $3$, although clearly there is only $1$ way.

Comment: Ahh, I'm not sure if I'm quite following...

Comment: If there was only $1$ veggie to choose from, only $1$ meat to choose from, and only $1$ cheese to choose from, then there would be just $1$ way to pick one topping from each category: choosing the only ones. However, if you apply the same logic you have applied in your answer to question 1, there would be $3$ ways.

Comment: @Richard: What is difficult about Regret's example? Suppose a different pizza place offers only onions as a vegetable topping, only ham as a meat topping, and only mozarella. How many different pizzas do _they_ have with one choice in each category? By your logic the answer should be $C(1,1)+C(1,1)+C(1,1)=3$, but I dare you to describe even two different ones.

Comment: So what's wrong with my solution for number one? The question asks the customer to pick one topping from each category. You have 7, 5, and 2 choices respectively with only one choice. I just don't see the error in #1.

Comment: If you have only one jeans and only a T-shirt, in how many ways can you get dressed? $1+1$ or $1\times 1?$ Do you have to add or multiply?

Comment: Multiply. So is my problem with the fact that I have addition signs?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem in $1)$.

Comment: Are my solutions to the other problems correct?

Comment: @mfl I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: @Richard: I think it would help if you added to your question why you think the answers you have come up with are correct. Unless someone else finishes writing up an answer before I do, I will be posting one.

Comment: @Regret Working on it right now.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

As said in comments the answer to $1)$ is $\binom{7}{1}\cdot \binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1}.$

The answer to $2)$ is $\binom{7}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2}$ (you choose two vegetables and you have $\binom{7}{2}$ possible ways to do it, and similar for meat and cheese. Remember that you have to multiply).

The answer to $5)$ is

$$\binom{7}{2}+\binom{7}{3}+\binom{7}{4}+\binom{7}{5}+\binom{7}{6}+\binom{7}{7}.$$ If you choose two vegetables you have  $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to do it, If you choose three vegetables you have  $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to do it, and so on. Use that

$$\binom{7}{2}+\binom{7}{3}+\binom{7}{4}+\binom{7}{5}+\binom{7}{6}+\binom{7}{7}=2^7-\binom{7}{0}-\binom{7}{1}$$ to get its value.

Could you get the solution to the other questions?

Comment: Does that notation represent Combinations? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Richard: $C(a,b)=\binom ab$

Comment: @Regret How does one know you aren't talking about Permutations?

Comment: @Regret is 3 C(7,1) * C(7,2) * C(5, 1) * C(5, 2) * C(2, 1) * C(2, 2)? And assuming #4 was incorrect, I'm really struggling with that one.

Comment: @Regret Ah, didn't know that. Only learned about the alternative notation in class. Take another glance haha!

Comment: @Richard: I was mistaken! Here is where you do add. I believe there are $\binom n0+\binom n1+\binom n2$ ways to choose either $0$, $1$, or $2$ from $n$.

Comment: @Regret That's for number 3, right?

Comment: @Richard: For example.

Comment: @Regret Do you mind working out and explaining the solution to #4 for me? Please?